# Image Stitching for Hundred Drone Images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-stitching, panoramas

I am trying to stitch hundred drone images to make panorama of a region. I have been using **cv2.createStitcher()**. However, it cannot find keypoints for more than 15 images. How can I improve my approach to stitch hundred of images?
Thank you!
Here, I have attached a demo of my attempt

```
import cv2
image_paths = ['a.jpg','b.jpg','c.jpg','d.jpg','e.jpg']
imgs = []
for i in range(len(image_paths)):
   imgs.append(cv2.imread(image_paths[i]))
   imgs[i]=cv2.resize(imgs[i],(0,0),fx=0.4,fy=0.4)
stitchy=cv2.createStitcher()
(dummy,output)=stitchy.stitch(imgs)
if dummy != cv2.STITCHER_OK:
   print("stitching ain't successful")
else:
   print('Your Panorama is ready!!!')
cv2.imwrite("output.png", output)
```

Comment: You can try the [stitching package](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching). I once stitched 40 Images with it. You probably have to Experiment with the settings. Follow the Tutorial for detailed informations about the stitching proccess

Comment: Please post all of the images you used in your code.

Comment: @Ann Zen, here is the drive link. Thank you!
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kV7qYp101Gy6GmfNEgzX96AVKP11ypEG?usp=sharing
I used the first five images of this folder.